# How to add a new font family in TinyMCE for Apex 23.1

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, apex

I'm using Apex 23.1 and I want to add a new font family in Tiny MCE with **url file reference** !
here's what I've done :

1- in **Initialization JavaScript Function** section

```
tinymce.init({
 /* ... */
 font_formats:
   "Andale Mono=andale mono,times; Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Arial Black=arial black,avant garde; Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino; Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif; Courier New=courier new,courier; Georgia=georgia,palatino; Helvetica=helvetica; Impact=impact,chicago; Oswald=oswald; Symbol=symbol; Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Terminal=terminal,monaco; Times New Roman=times new roman,times; Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva; Verdana=verdana,geneva; Webdings=webdings; Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats;peyda=peyda",
});

tinymce.init({
 /* ... */
 content_style:
   "@import url('#WORKSPACE_FILES#Peyda-Regular.ttf');",
});
```

2- in **inline css** section for page

```
@font-face{
font-family:'Peyda';
src:url('#WORKSPACE_FILES#Peyda-Regular.ttf') format('truetype') !important;
}
```

But it didn't apply and even i can't see my new font **Peyda** in font select !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I asked here and **[Louis Moreaux](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/r/apexds/community/profile?username=louis-moreaux&session=513712806204927)** had answered me there :

for css inline section :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Peyda";
  src: url('#APP_FILES#Peyda-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and for Initialization JavaScript Function
section :

```
function(options) {
    options.editorOptions.font_css = ["#APP_FILES#Peyda-Regular.ttf"]; //Reference your custom fonts **note : here I should reference the css file not the ttf** 
    // Add the font family selector
    if ( Array.isArray( options.editorOptions.toolbar ) ) { 
    options.editorOptions.toolbar.push( { name: "fontfamily", items: [ "fontfamily" ] } ); 
    } else { 
    options.editorOptions.toolbar += " fontfamily"; 
    }

    options.editorOptions.font_family_formats = "Andale Mono=andale mono,times; Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Arial Black=arial black,avant garde; Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino; Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif; Courier New=courier new,courier; Georgia=georgia,palatino; Helvetica=helvetica; Impact=impact,chicago; Symbol=symbol; Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Terminal=terminal,monaco; Times New Roman=times new roman,times; Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva; Verdana=verdana,geneva; Webdings=webdings; Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats; Peyda=Peyda" // Declare the fonts ( mine is peyda the last one)
    return options;
}
```

special thanks to **[Louis Moreaux](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/r/apexds/community/profile?username=louis-moreaux&session=513712806204927)**